# Excel/Google Sheets Offset and Transpose formula question

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, offset, transpose

I have a query regarding the `OFFSET` and `TRANSPOSE` formulas. I have the following two sheets set up in Google Sheets (originally in Excel):

First sheet:
[image: First Sheet]

Formula in cell B2: `=transpose('Form responses 1'!A2:BB2)` (original)

`=transpose(offset('Form responses 1'!A$2:BB$2,COLUMNS($A$2:A2)-1,0))` (current)

Formula in cell C2: `=transpose('Form responses 1'!A3:BB3)`

Formula in cell D2: `=transpose('Form responses 1'!A4:BB4)`

I would like the references to increase by row (vertically down) rather than by column (horizontally right) when I drag across to copy the formula.

Second sheet:
[image: Second Sheet]

As you can see in the first sheet, I am trying to `TRANSPOSE` data from the second sheet using said formula. However when I go to drag the formula across (horizontally) it references the column when instead I need it to reference the row (if I drag it downwards it works fine but that is not what I need in this particular case).

I understand I need to implement a `OFFSET` function, something along the lines of: `=transpose(offset('Form responses 1'!A$2:BB$2,COLUMNS($A$2:A2)-1,0))`

I am unsure of what the last part would need to be, `COLUMNS($A$2:A2)-1,0`, what should I change this to to get the desire result?

If I have not explained thoroughly enough please let me know, thanks.

Comment: try out =transpose(query('Form responses 1'!A:BB, "Select *",-1) this should work I guess? if you share a sheet with dummy & desired content then we can help. the -1 removes headers. Also if you need to query multiple forms let me know and I'll write an answer and adapt the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the solution I play around with it, albeit, I have implemented Ed's suggestion below successfully. I appreciate your time.

Comment: no poblemo! if you need to query multiple forms you can pass them into the first part of the query argument as an array so =query({'Form 1'!A:C;'Form 2'!A:C}, "Select *") you can also append import range at the start if forms are held on different sheets. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrayformula and you won't have to drag anything. Try:

```
=arrayformula(transpose('Form responses 1'!A$1:BB$4))
```

Comment: I've tried `=arrayformula(transpose('Form responses 1'!A$2:BB$2))` in cell B2, is that what you meant? It works but how do I get into the adjacent cells without dragging/copying it across?

Comment: Try it like I have it. Put it in A1. It will pick up the headers and all rows through 4.

Comment: @Env67 Here is the test I did. Copy it if you need to edit it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ty2EfdIguGFCbWiLTDlA_Cs9TpQF1nh4u8f0cri5lpU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you, it works flawlessly and I can expand it to include as many columns as required in one swoop. I appreciate your time, cheers!